# How to find the single element from embedded document in nodejs mongodb native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I want to find a single element from embedded document in MongoDB.
Here are my documents of user collection in MongoDB:-

```
[
       {
         "userId":"001",
        "userName":"abc"
        "subscriptionDetails" : [
            {
            "planId" : "1",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : true,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570927981,
            
            },
            {
            "planId" : "2",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : true,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570927909,
            
             },
            {
            "planId" : "3",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : false,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570978,
            
             }

         ]
     },
    {
        "userId":"002",
        "userName":"abc"
        "subscriptionDetails" : [
            {
            "planId" : "1",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : true,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570927981,
            
            }

         ]
     }
]
```

My nodejs function to find the single element from embedded documents by nodejs native driver:-

```
var Plan=await db.collection("user").findOne(
        {
             userId:001,
            'subscriptionDetails.current':false,
            'subscriptionDetails.isExpired':false
            
        },
        {
                'projection':{ "_id": 0,'subscriptionDetails.$':1 }
        }
        )
console.log(plan)
```

But the response of this function is:-

```
{ 
 subscriptionDetails: 
   [  {
            "planId" : "1",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : true,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570927981,
            
      }
 ] 
}
```

But the expected output is:-

```
{ 
 subscriptionDetails: 
   [    {
            "planId" : "3",
            "isExpired" : false,
            "current" : false,
            "timeStamp" : 1592570978,
            
             }
 ] 
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: if I'm not wrong, it should be `subscriptionDetails.0: 1` instead of `subscriptionDetails.$ :1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why the query is not working as expected?**

There are certain limitations when using the positional operator `$` for query result projection. One of them is:

> The query document should only contain a single condition on the array
> field being projected. Multiple conditions may override each other
> internally and lead to undefined behavior.

Source - [Array fields limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations)

In your query,

```
db.collection("user").findOne(
  {
    userId:001,
    'subscriptionDetails.current':false,
    'subscriptionDetails.isExpired':false
  },
  {
    'projection':{ "_id": 0,'subscriptionDetails.$':1 }
  }
)
```

you have 2 conditions on the array field being projected. This is why the query result is not what is expected.

**The fix:**

The easy fix would be to reduce the filter conditions on the `subscriptionDetails` to just one. However, if reducing the filter conditions is not an option, you can make use of [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) to compose the filter conditions. `$elemMatch` would limit the content of the `subscriptionDetails` array to contain only the first element matching the condition specified. Something like this:

```
db.collection("user").findOne(
  { 
    userId: "001", 
    subscriptionDetails: {
      $elemMatch: {
        current: false,
        isExpired: false,
      }
    } 
  },
  { _id: 0, 'subscriptionDetails.$':1 }
);
```